# How to initialize log4net GlobalContext properties in configuration file

Tags: .net, configuration, log4net, configuration-files

Is there a way to define global context property in the configuration file if I don't want to set it in the code like

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["AppName"] = "MyCoolApp";
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log4net does not provide this functionality, but you can easily build it yourself:

- Store some key / value pairs in a configuration file of your choice
- Read the key value pairs on start up and assign it to the global context

The second part would be something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> pairs = ReadGlobalContextConfiguration();
foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    log4net.GlobalContext.Properties[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
}
```

The first part depends on where you want to store the information. There are many options:

- Configuration Section in App/Web.config
- Simple Xml File
- Simple Text File with `key=value` entries per line